# A Font Called "Design"

Tags: fonts

I've used a font called Design, but it seems like it was not transferred with my new computer.  I can't seem to find it on the web.  Is anyone familiar with this font and where I can find it?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a screenshot, possibly from some old work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a font with the name 'design':

http://www.fonts.com/font/mindcandy-studios/design

Here's another one:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/dsgnhaus/design/

They both appear to be based off the same 'design' (no pun intended. Is that even a pun?). Not sure if one is a knock off of the other, or if they are both based on some historic face.

Comment: I'd say they're the same font. One is copyrighted by 2rebels, and the other is by Mindcandy Studios who distribute fonts for 2rebels.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet good catch!